# binary crossentropy type error problem:TypeError: Invalid keyword argument(s) in `compile()`: ({'matrics'},)

Tags: python, image, keras, conv-neural-network

```
classifier.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',matrics=["accuracy"])
```

TypeError: Invalid keyword argument(s) in `compile()`: ({'matrics'},). Valid keyword arguments include "cloning", "experimental_run_tf_function", "distribute", "target_tensors", or "sample_weight_mode".

Why is the error happening

Answer (score 0):

You should write `metrics` instead of `matrics`.